# How to migrate 700+ PWA sites to SharePoint/Project Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, project-online, pwa

I have identified [one article from MS](http://%E2%80%8Bhttps://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/projectonline/migrate-to-project-online-from-project-server) which is explaining how to migrate PWA site to Project Online which involves manual effort. But we are having 796 PWA sites, so manual effort is highly error prone and difficult to maintain as well.

Is there any better way for migrating PWA sites to Project Online? Any tools are available to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Quest / Metalogix Content Matrix, and ShareGate are probably the most popular options for migrating to O365.